# Получить смещение UTC из временной зоны

Tags: c#, время, timezone, utc

От гео API ко мне приходит часовой пояс в формате `регион/город`, в информации о пользователе я хочу хранить именно UTC offset типа `int`, как это можно сделать?

Пример:

Для `Europe/Moscow` нужно получить значение `3`, для `Mexico/BajaNorte` - значение `-8`

Comment: Очень плохая идея. Например в `Mexico/BajaNorte` сейчас вообще-то `-7`…

Comment: Тогда вам нужно еще статус Daylight savings ещё хранить, переход на летнее время. Смысл в этом какой, если операционка всё знает про часовые пояса? Храните название, а для работы опрашивайте `TimeZoneInfo`

Comment: @aepot, справедливое замечание, спасибо. Я новичок, поэтому даже не подумал о таком) Руководствовался лишь тем, что каждый раз дергать `TimeZoneInfo` более затратно, чем просто хранить однажды подсчитанный отступ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid?view=net-7.0)

```cs
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Moscow").BaseUtcOffset); // 03:00:00
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mexico/BajaNorte").BaseUtcOffset); // -08:00:00
```

Также если вы запускаете это в докер контейнере, нужно дополнительно проверить что ICU библиотека установлена [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> On Windows systems, FindSystemTimeZoneById tries to match id to the subkey names of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones branch of the registry. On Linux and macOS, it uses time zone information available in the ICU Library.

В дефолтном Debian-based образе она должна уже быть установлена.